# How can several tables in a PostgreSql DB be updated by inserting a Pandas DF into existing rows (based on columns)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have tried UPDATE with psycopg2 but get error messages the closest to the objective is when INSERT is used but its not quite there yet (ref. tables further below); a solution using sqalchemy would also be welcome.
None of the tables depend on each other.
Code excerpt below:

```
# There are three Postgres tables in the DB whose names are also the same as the symbol names.  
Symbols = ['AUDCAD', 'AUDJPY', 'AUDUSD']

# The variables below named macd_480, macd_840, macd_1518, macd_2400 are 1D NumPy arrays.
# They are generated for each symbol e.g AUDCAD will have its own variables with values. 
stacked_MACD = pandas.DataFrame(
                          numpy.column_stack((macd_480, macd_840, macd_1518, macd_2400))
                               ).drop(index=0).values.tolist()

# Create the column names to be inserted to Postgres tables as a list.
macd_column_names = ','.join(['macd_480', 'macd_840', 'macd_1518', 'macd_2400'])

for i in symbols:       
    # Insertion of each variable values into each respective table (audcad, audjpy, audusd).  
    query_insert_macd = """INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s""" % (i, macd_column_names)

    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor_postgresql, query_insert_macd, stacked_MACD)
```

Example of how one of the tables looks like before attempting to insert/update/merge:

```
   row_no    O   H   L   C  macd_480  macd_840  macd_1518  macd_2400
0      1    10  20  30  40     None      None        None      None
1      2    10  20  30  40     None      None        None      None
2      3    10  20  30  40     None      None        None      None
3      4    10  20  30  40     None      None        None      None
```

Table after the insertion (using the INSERT INTO above):

```
    row_no     O     H     L     C  macd_480  macd_840  macd_1518  macd_2400
0       1     10    20    30    40     None      None       None       None
1       2     10    20    30    40     None      None       None       None
2       3     10    20    30    40     None      None       None       None
3       4     10    20    30    40     None      None       None       None
4       5   None  None  None  None       50        60         70         80
5       6   None  None  None  None       50        60         70         80
6       7   None  None  None  None       50        60         70         80
7       8   None  None  None  None       50        60         70         80
```

OBJECTIVE - Each table should appear as follows:

```
    row_no   O   H   L   C  macd_480  macd_840  macd_1518  macd_2400
0       1   10  20  30  40       50        60         70         80
1       2   10  20  30  40       50        60         70         80
2       3   10  20  30  40       50        60         70         80
3       4   10  20  30  40       50        60         70         80
```

Comment: If you tried `UPDATE` and it failed, provide the statement and the full traceback. And how do you match existing records with `stacked_MACD` dataframe: do you use `row_no` as `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: 1) Do not use Python string formatting to build a query string. See [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for why not and proper way to build dynamic sql. 2) This `stacked_MACD` is only supplying part of the row values. There is nothing in there that matches up with whatever the Primary Key is in the existing data.  3) Read up on INSERT [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).